# Oscillation of a Function in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let oscillation be defined as
$$\omega_f(x):=\inf_{\delta > 0} \text{diam}(f(B(x,\delta)))$$

(1) Show that for the function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x\leq 0\\1 & \text{if }x > 0\end{cases},$$ $\omega_f(0)=1$.

(2) Show that for the function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} (-1)^n & \text{if }x=\frac{1}{n}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$ $\omega_f(0)=2$.

---

I'm not sure how to prove this, as this definition of oscillation is different from others I've seen. I suppose I'd start with breaking $f$ up into cases. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

a) Fix a $\delta>0$. Consider the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$, i.e. a ball around zero. Observe the image of the interval is
\begin{align}
f((-\delta, \delta)) = \{0, 1\}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\operatorname{diam}f((-\delta, \delta))= 1. 
\end{align}
Since this holds for any $\delta$, we see that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\operatorname{diam}f((-\delta, \delta)) = 1. 
\end{align}

b) Same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you have no doubts, $B(x,\delta) = (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ and $f(A) = \{f(x):x\in A\}$, so you need to check for all $\delta$ what is the diameter of an $f$-image of an open interval around $x$, and find for which $\delta$ this diameter is the smallest. Hint: if $\delta_1 < \delta_2$ then $f(B(x,\delta_1))\subseteq f(B(x,\delta_2))$, which can tell you something about how their diameters are related. From that you can realize whether you need to care about all values of $\delta$, or only about very small ones. In the latter case, for both of your examples these diameters are quite easy to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$\operatorname{diam}(S)=\sup\{|x-y| : x,y \in S\}$$

So  for the first one, every open ball about zero intersects some $x<0$ and some $y \geq 0$ in which case the diameter will always be $|1-0|=1$. From this we can gather that the infimum over all these diameters is actually a minimum since it is acheived and it is $1$. The same argument can be made for the second, since there are always two consecutive $n \in \mathbb N$ in some neighborhood of $0$ which in turn implies that the diameter will be $|-1^n-1^{n+1}|=2$ (always) in any neighborhood of $0$.

The reason that these are easy to calculate is that the diameter is really constant for each neighborhood in question.

To work with the definitions a little bit, see if you can prove that a function $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\operatorname{osc}_f(x)=0$.